# Multiple digital signatures

Tags: digital-signature, ip

I have the following case scenario: 
One document that needs to be signed digitally (using an external signing service) by 4 different people. The 4 people must be present while signing the document at the same place.

How can I create a situation where "digitally speaking" is ensure that the 4 people were signing while being together?

I thought that if each one of them uses the same computer (each of them logging in the signing service) that would be a way since it is the same datamachine (same IP). Are there any others?

Comment: What do you *exactly* consider "together", i.e. what is the use case why they need to be somehow together? Being logged in in the same computer can also be done if they log in from remote. If you want to ensure physical presence at the same place at the same time just having the same IP address  is not enough.

Comment: Tell us a bit more about *why* they need to sign it in each others presence. Is it because they don't trust each other and must each witness the others signing?  Does it have something to do with guaranteeing a number of events happen in a certain sequence? Or is there another reason why they need to be together, in the same room?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, well the need to be together is because it is required by the law that they are together :) , so in a way must each witness the others signing. It is in the context of signing  an agreement for marriage  (the couple plus 2 whitnesses)

Comment: @CarlosGómezPérez: the law which requires this is is the way a specific underlying problem was solved in the non-digital area. I'm not even sure if this law would allow digital signatures even if you could guarantee that the persons are together. The real question is what is the underlying problem is which this law tried to solve. And then you can ask how to solve this underlying problem in a digital way.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-technical solution: How about taking a picture of the four of them in the same room together, possibly holding a newspaper to give a "no-earlier-than" date, and maybe a printout of the document, and add the picture to the document to be signed?

I'm fairly confident that this would convince most people that the four people in the picture came together in order to sign the document in question, especially if the signature service gave the same date for when the signatures were made as the date visible on the newspaper in the picture.

This is assuming that you can't have a trusted person present that can simply vouch for the four people all being there with his own signature on the document.

If it's just that you must each witness that the others have signed, you might do it like this:

A signs the document.

B signs A's signature.

C signs B's signature.

D signs C's signature.

A signs D's signature.

B signs A's 2nd signature.

C signs B's 2nd signature.

(You need B and C to sign again to prove that they know about D's signature, too. If you stop after A signs D's signature, you have no way to know whether B and C know that D signed).

I also have an idea that uses zero-knowledge proofs, but this is so convoluted that I don't think it would interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking, but you can use Shamir's Secret Splitting to divide a passphrase to a private key between 4 different people. It would require all 4 of them to be present in order to reconstitute the passphrase and issue a signature. As long as the reconstituted passphrase is not exposed during the procedure and is then immediately destroyed, you can use this process multiple times.

Of course, there is nothing preventing them from colluding together and recovering the passphrase if all 4 of them decide to subvert the process.

Comment: But the 4 of them need to sign the document, that means 4 different passphrase I guess (?)

Comment: Not really. But if you require their original signatures, you could just add a 5th "virtual" persona which stood for the shared secret and require that this persona also sign the document in order for it to be valid.

Comment: @CarlosGómezPérez right, if you need to have 4 actually different digital signatures, then yes. Alternatively, don't give these 4 people actual private keys, but only passphrases. This way all 4 would need to be present to actually sign the document in front of the system with actual private keys.

Comment: Umm a bit confused now...dont really understand the difference between the passphrases and the privake key. In there any source from where I can read more about it?

Comment: A private key is what is doing the actual signing. It is usually not directly usable without first inputting a passphrase that protects it (it's encrypted itself using that passphrase). Digital signing is not easy to get right, so I strongly recommend you invest some time into learning all the details before implementing any solutions.